# css a nav is hiding my text

Tags: html, css

Hi I have some difficulties with my paragraphs. It's supposed to be contains between the Header and the Nav (bottom) So I would like to know how can I unhide my text from the nav. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdiamond/5gEjL/4/)

```
*{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
    color: black;
}
.header{
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #11a7ab;
}

.nav{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #4f597b;
    overflow:hidden;
    zoom: 1;
}
.nav a{
    display: block;
    height: 60px; 
    line-height: 60px;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    @include transition-duration;
}
.nav a:first-child{
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
.nav a.active{
    border-top: 3px solid #11a7ab;
}
.nav a i{
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.panel{
    position: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
}

.left{

}
.right{

}
.left{
    @include transform(translate3D(-50%, 0, 0));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you use `position:absolute` for your header, the section will be overlapped by it. So you can try using some `margin-top` which is equal to the height of the header like this:

```
.view {
  position: relative;
  margin-top:60px;
}
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/5gEjL/7/)

Answer (score 2):

`enter code here`You can add the following to your CSS
.view{ margin-top: 60px; }

This will allow you to separate the header from your content section